# Re-indexing a pandas Series extracted from DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

## Problematic

Let us say that I have a DataFrame df of n rows like this:

| Precipitation | Discharge |
|:------12-------:|:-----16-----:|
|:------10-------:|:-----15-----:|
|:------12-------:|:-----16-----:|
|:------10-------:|:-----15-----:|
...
|:------12-------:|:-----16-----:|
|:------10-------:|:-----15-----:|

Rows are automatically indexed from 1 to n. When we extract one column for example:

```
series = df.loc[5:,['Precipitation']]
or
series = df.Precipitation[5:]
```

The extracted series tends to be like:
    Precipitation
5 16
6 17
7 18
...
n 15

So the question is how can we modify the generic indexing from 5 to n to 0 to n-5.

> Note that I have tried series.reindex() and series.reset_index() but neither of them works...
>   Currently I do series.tolist() to solve the problem but is there any way more elegant and smarter?

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Your question is unclear and the example is not complete; e.g. there are no numbers 17-19 present in your dataframe

Comment: @MarcelZoll Well it is just an example, so I used **...** to make it less complex. Basically, when you extract a sub-seires from a pandas dataframe like `series = df.loc[5:,['Precipitation']]`. The extracted series is automatically indexed from 5. So I wonder how to reindexit from zero. Thanks

Comment: I think need `series = df.loc[5:,['Precipitation']].reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for replying! Tried `drop =True` but did not work...

Comment: `df.Precipitation[:-5]`

Comment: @piRSquared Thx man. But it does a different thing XD. So basically I would like to generate a sub-series discarding the first x elements and then append some other values to this series to give it the same length as it used to be. Finally put it back to the dataframe. I do this because I would like to calculate the correlations between these shifted values. So I am sorry that I didn't say my original purpose in the post. But your answer does a different extraction...

Comment: pd.Series(data=df.loc[5:,['Precipitation']].values, index=whatever_index_you_now_want)

Comment: @emmet02 Thanky you emmet. Your method works. But .values does more or less the same thing as .tolist(). No means to offense. Your method as well as mine remind me of `if cond==True:`...

Comment: .values is very different from .tolist(). You will see this if you ever have to use extremely large datasets.

Comment: @emmet02 Yes that is true. Thanks for reminding me of that.

Comment: What output do you get when using `reset_index(drop=True)`? It worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to select the first n-5 rows of your column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'col2': [3,4,3,2,5,9,7]})

df.loc[:len(df)-5,['col1']]
```

You may want to read up on slicing with pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-ranges

EDIT:

I think I misunderstood, and what you instead want is to 'reset' your index. You can do that with the method reset_index()

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'col2': [3,4,3,2,5,9,7]})

df = df.loc[5:,['col1']]

df.reset_index(drop=True)
```